# Need some assistance with sorting a linked list

Tags: c

I am working on a school assignment and I am making an int linkedlist and it should have a function to sort it. I'm pretty sure I got the linkedlinks right based on the output. The sort function should swap nodes, not values. I am getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) message, not sure what it means or why. I'm looking for help on why it doesn't work. I am still pretty bad with pointers so I assume it is an issue with that. Also my sort is insertion sort

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;

node *pHead = NULL; // head of list
node *pCurr = NULL; // current node
int count = 0;

void create(int data) {

    node *pNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    pNode->data = data;
    pNode->next = NULL;
    pNode->prev = NULL;


    pHead = pCurr = pNode;
    count += 1;
}

void add(int data) {
    if (pHead == NULL) {
        return create(data);
    }

    node *pNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    pNode->data = data;
    pNode->next = NULL;

    pNode->prev = pCurr;
    pCurr->next = pNode;
    pCurr = pNode;

    count += 1;
}

int size() {
    return count;
}

void print() {
    node *pNode = pHead;
    while (pNode != NULL) {
        printf("[%d]->", pNode->data);
        pNode = pNode->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void sort(node *current) {

    pHead = current;
    node *pInsert = pHead;
    current = current->next;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (current->data >= pInsert->data) {
                node *pTemp = current;
                current = pInsert;
                pInsert = pTemp;
            }
            pInsert = pInsert->prev;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    print();
}
```

Comment: From a quick glance, I see that you have no NULL protection, so you could potentially try and dereference a null pointer

Comment: You are not actually swapping the nodes. You are just changing what `current` and `pInsert` point at.

Comment: @jxh how do I swap the nodes?

Comment: Change what `next` and `prev` point to in all the nodes affected by the swap.

Comment: `Current= current->next` will cause a seg fault later on if your current is the last node. Add a NULL pointer guard at `if (current->data >= pInsert->data)`

Comment: would it be better to use while loops instead and go until current and pinsert is null?

Comment: I got it to run now but it just prints back in the same order, I guess its what @jxh said about just changing what the pointer goes to

Comment: yup, now when you are dealing with linked lists, especially when you have the prev/next pointers, to move things around, you'll need to have a delete function and an insert function. The delete function basically takes a node, and does something like this: `node->prev->next = node->next` that should effectively delete it from the list. your insert function would then look something like `nodeIWantToInsert->next = insertionPoint->next, nodeIWantToInsert->previous = insertionPoint, nodeIWantToInsert->next->previous = nodeIWantToInsert`

Comment: searching this site for the `[c]` tag in combination with the last four words of this question's title would probably have been a fruitful endeavor. I assure you, you're not the first person troubled by sorting linked lists.

Comment: @WhozCraig I did look around and on google but I was having trouble doing it

Answer (score 3):

To figure out how to swap adjacent nodes in a linked list, it is instructive to draw a picture. Imagine nodes A, B, C, D arranged in linked list order, where the next pointers are green wires, and the previous pointers are red wires. Then, imagine what happens to the wires if you just moved the B and C nodes into each other's position.

[image]

Now, figure out what pointer manipulations you would have to do to get the picture to look nice and pretty again.

Answer (score 1):

```
void sort(node *current) {

    node *pTemp, *pInsert = current;
    current = current->next;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
         if (current != NULL && pInsert != NULL && current->data >= pInsert->data) {

/*start delete node*/
          if (pInsert->prev != NULL)
           pInsert->prev->next = pInsert->next;
          if (pInsert->next != NULL)
           pInsert->next->prev = pInsert->prev 
/*end delete node*/
/*start add node*/
          pInsert->next = current->next;
          pInsert->prev = current;
          if (current->next != NULL)
           current->next->prev = pInsert;
          current->next = pInsert;
/*end add node*/
            }
            pInsert = pInsert->prev;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    print();
}
```

Try this. Basically you delete your node from its current position, by having the previous node's next pointer skip the node in question and point to the one after, and then you have the next node skip the node in question and point to the previous node.

Then you insert your node by having the next pointer from your node in question point to the next node from your insertion point... (gets a little confusing when talking about the next of the next/ next of the previous).

**important**: Also, when dealing with those pointers, make sure to have your NULL checks!

Comment: got rid of it with the harder to read multiple dereferences ;), ie `node->next->prev`

Comment: @AdamWolf that's not the only problem. This also spells failure for a list that, sorted, changes which node is the head. The caller will never see that change.

Comment: Oh yes, and I removed that bit also because of that and it might not hurt to throw in a find head/tail function. ie search until you hit the null

Comment: I'm getting a core dumped message from this? using while loops seemed to fix it but It doesnt print right. the main while loop is doing current->next != null and the inner while loop is doing pInsert->prev != null

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I'd updated it with all the NULL checks needed

Comment: @engineer14 Hey, I am still having problems. The core dumped error still happens.

Comment: The only way i can envision a core dump happening for this function up top is if you are passing it a NULL pointer